# How to call a function only, when in a specific case in a switch case for unit test?

Tags: c#, nunit, nsubstitute

So I have a class Doorcontrol that can have 4 states

```
public enum DoorControlState
{
    DoorClosed,
    DoorOpening,
    DoorOpen,
    DoorBreached

}
```

To open the door an accescode is needed, the code is then validated and if it's correct the door is opened. If the door is not in the Closed state nothing should happen. It should go like this RequestEntry(id)[Doorcontrol]->ValidateEntryRequest(id)[IUserValidation]->OK[Doorcontrol]->Open[IDoor]->change state to DoorOpening. Idoor then calls DoorOpen and the state changes to DoorOpen and so on.

I have implemented the DoorControl class as follows

```
public class DoorControl
{
    private IDoor _door;
    private IEntryNotification _entryNotification;
    private IUserValidation _userValidation;
    private DoorControlState _doorControlState;
    private int _id;

    public DoorControl(IDoor door, IEntryNotification entryNotification, IUserValidation userValidation, DoorControlState doorControlState)
    {
        _door = door;
        _entryNotification = entryNotification;
        _userValidation = userValidation;
        _doorControlState = doorControlState;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        switch (_doorControlState)
        {
            case DoorControlState.DoorClosed:

                bool foo = RequestEntryId();
                if (foo)
                {
                    _door.Open();
                    _doorControlState = DoorControlState.DoorOpening;
                }
                break;
            case DoorControlState.DoorOpening:
                _door.Close();
                _doorControlState = DoorControlState.DoorOpen;
                break;
            case DoorControlState.DoorOpen:
                // Do stuff....                  
                break;
            case DoorControlState.DoorBreached:
                // Do stuff
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException();
            }
    }

    private bool RequestEntryId()
    {
        bool maybeFoo = _userValidation.ValidateEnetryRequest();
        if (maybeFoo = true)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void DoorOpened()
    {
        //
    }

    public void DoorClosed()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

}

The UserValidation and Door classes are implemented as Interfaces

```
public interface IUserValidation
{
    bool ValidateEnetryRequest();

}

public interface IDoor
{

    void Open();

    void Close();

}
```

I am testing my code using Nunit and NSubstitute

```
namespace DoorControl.Unit.Test
{
[TestFixture]
public class DoorControlUnitTest
{
    private DoorControl _uut;
    private IDoor _door;
    private IEntryNotification _entryNotification;
    private IUserValidation _userValidation;
    private DoorControlState _doorControlState;

    [SetUp]

    public void SetUp()
    {
        _door = Substitute.For<IDoor>();
        _entryNotification = Substitute.For<IEntryNotification>();
        _userValidation = Substitute.For<IUserValidation>();
        _doorControlState = DoorControlState.DoorClosed;

    _uut = new DoorControl(_door, _entryNotification, _userValidation, _doorControlState);
    }

    [Test]
    public void InputCorrectId()
    {
        _userValidation.ValidateEnetryRequest().Returns(true);
        _uut.RequestEntryId();  // Can't called that cause it's private

        _door.Received().Open();

    }

}
}
```

I can't figure out how to make it call RequestEntryId only when it's in the Doorclosed state and ignore it if it's in another state.

Edit: What state the Doorcontrol is in should be hidden from everybody else.

Comment: Consider applying strategy pattern instead of using switch statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void InputCorrectId()
    {
        _userValidation.ValidateEnetryRequest().Returns(true);
        if(_doorControlState == DoorControlState.DoorClosed){
            _uut.RequestEntryId();  // Make it public
        }
        _door.Received().Open();

    }
```

Or into the doorcontrol class like:

```
 case DoorControlState.DoorClosed:
    RequestEntryId();
```

Comment: That requires my test to know the state of the DoorControl I would like to avoid anybody knowing what state DoorControl is in.

Comment: run it into the class run control, I updated my answer

Comment: I had a mistake in the code somewhere else that kept me from getting it to work, once that was fixed this worked as it should. Thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking: when you say "I can't figure out how to make it call RequestEntryId only when it's in the Doorclosed state and ignore it if it's in another state." do you mean the unit test? I can't figure out why you would want to do that. Please provide more info and I'll update this answer if I can help.

I did notice a couple of things that might help you though. First `RequestEntryId` has a problem:

```
private bool RequestEntryId()
{
    bool maybeFoo = _userValidation.ValidateEnetryRequest();
    if (maybeFoo = true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here `maybeFoo = true` is an assignment which overwrites the result of `ValidateEntryRequest()`. I think you intended a comparison with `==`, but the whole method can be simplified to:

```
private bool RequestEntryId()
{
    return _userValidation.ValidateEnetryRequest();
}
```

With that fixed we can run a few tests to check how the public `Run` method behaves. Given your `SetUp` creates a doorcontrol already in a `Closed` state, we can test that the door opens for valid users, and doesn't open  for invalid users.

```
    [Test]
    public void ClosedDoorOpensWhenUserIsValid()
    {
        _userValidation.ValidateEnetryRequest().Returns(true);
        _uut.Run();
        _door.Received().Open();
    }

    [Test]
    public void ClosedDoorDoesNotOpenWhenUserInvalid()
    {
        _userValidation.ValidateEnetryRequest().Returns(false);
        _uut.Run();
        _door.DidNotReceive().Open();
    }
```

We can also check the validation is not repeated for an already opened door:

```
    [Test]
    public void OpenDoorDoesNotRevalidate()
    {
        _userValidation.ValidateEnetryRequest().Returns(true);
        _uut.Run();

        _userValidation.ClearReceivedCalls();
        _uut.Run();
        _userValidation.DidNotReceive().ValidateEnetryRequest();
    }
```

Hope this gives you some ideas for testing this.